# SQL installation on Amazon Web Services

Tags: sql

Folks, I have question this morning that hopefully one of you techies can answer – during past few months, I have been heavily involved in preparing several SQL certifications study guides as it’s my desire to secure Microsoft Certified Solutions Associate (MCSA) or associate level. While I have previous experiences within this skill set and wanted to sharpen it by obtaining further experiences and hopefully securing this certification, it has been quite challenging setting up a home lab that allows me to create environment similar to what the big dogs use nowadays – windows server/several sql instances/virtualization and all that – due to lack of proper hardware or cost. In any case, my question today is to seek your advices and guidance on other possible options, particularly if this task can be accomplished using ***Amazons AWS*** – I understand they offer some level of space that can be used as playground or if one want to extend the capacity, subscription is an option. So, if I was to subscribe the paid version of it, is it possible to install all software needed to practice and experiment all needed technologies to complete and or master contents on the training kit. Again, I’m already using my small home network and have all proper software, but just feel that it’s not enough as some areas require higher computing power to properly test or rung specific areas..

Comment: What kind of SQL? You should be able to fire up an instance and install whatever you please.

Answer (score 0):

Short: Yes

You can create a micro instance for free and install whatever you want on it. If your not familiar with using the CLI, it can be a bit daunting but there are plenty of guides online.
They also offer an RDS service where, they will allow you to set up a database instance and will maintain it for you but it's not free.

**Edit**
Link to there MS Server Page

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

Azure is the windows cloud service, I think the comment was have you considered looking at azure instead of AWS

Comment: I intend on installing SQL Server 2012 and or 2008 for practice purposes - someone mentioned howabout Azure? what about it?

Comment: Thanks to you all who responded my earlier question - I will give a serious consideration on Azure rather than AWS as many suggested its the best route to accomplish my planned adventure...Again, Thanks much.....Ciao